# join two table, input and order by two different column

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

```
bsl_prioritas_perasat                 rek_perasat
+=========+========+=====+            +=======+==========+======+
|RUPER    |CODE    |SORT |            |CODE   |NAME      |SUB   |
+=========+========+=====+            +=======+==========+======+
|CB2RA    |R0004   |1    |            |R0004  |JASA 1    |AKA   |
|CB2RA    |R0006   |2    |            |R0006  |JASA 2    |AKB   |
|CB3RI    |R0006   |1    |            |R0008  |JASA VK   |VK    |
|CB3RI    |R0008   |2    |            |R0026  |ACCOMT    |AKOM  |
+=========+========+=====+            +=======+==========+======+
```

Input will be **RUPER** and **SUB**.

If **RUPER** exist on `bsl_prioritas_perasat`, then it will order by **SORT** and **NAME**, and if **CODE** doesn't exist/NULL for that **RUPER** on `bsl_prioritas_perasat`, it will put on last

If **RUPER** doesn't exist, it will ignore **SORT** and it will order by **NAME**

example:

```
1st                    2nd                    3rd
RUPER=CB2RA, SUB=AK    RUPER=CB3RI, SUB=AK    RUPER=CB5DB, SUB=AK
Result:                Result:                Result:
+==========+           +==========+           +==========+
|NAME      |           |NAME      |           |NAME      |
+==========+           +==========+           +==========+
|JASA 1    |           |JASA 2    |           |ACCOMT    |
|JASA 2    |           |ACCOMT    |           |JASA 1    |
|ACCOMT    |           |JASA 1    |           |JASA 2    |
+==========+           +==========+           +==========+
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: It looks like you want an exact match on RUPER and a prefix match on SUB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll should be able to use a `LEFT JOIN` with an `IFNULL` and a default sort value, something like:

```
SELECT name, sort
FROM (SELECT r.NAME, IFNULL(b.SORT, 100),
  FROM rek_perasat AS r LEFT JOIN bsl_prioritas_perasat AS b
    ON r.CODE = b.CODE AND b.RUPER = ?
  WHERE r.SUB LIKE ? + '%');
```

**Update:** Added subselect.

Comment: I need order by SORT, but when I tried to add `order by SORT`, I can't get null on last? I tried with `order by SORT is null` but the order is desc?

Comment: How about a subselect for this - `SELECT name, sort FROM (SELECT r.name AS name, IFNULL(b.SORT, 100) AS sort FROM ...`?

Comment: Thanks, it works. You can edit and add that in your answer and I will accept it. :)